# Video.js Dynamically Loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video

First i need to say what my english is no the best.
Im trying to load a a php file with this javascript code:

```
function reload() {
var id = <?=$id?>;
$('#vidid').load('other.php?&id='+id,true);

}
```

with this

```
<a href="#videodiv2" onclick="reload()" class="button">Mostrar envio</a>
<div id="vidid"> </div>
```

If i put the code of "other.php" direct in the main page it works, but if i use the "function reload()" Dont work.
I search and find this, so is incorrect do in the way what i explain
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/setup.md

I can read english better than write it XD. But i can t make it works with that manual

```
videojs("example_video_1", {}, function(){
// Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
```

That is the javascript code right? so in "example_video_1" i should replace for "vidid"?
and replace "function()" for "function reload()"?
and what i should write in // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
NOTE:Im use the video.js variation what allow to show youtube video + autoplay.

Sorry for my BAD english :S

---

Thanks for the code bloodyKnuckles it works perfect with mp4 file but with the plugin of youtube says "Se ha producido un error intentalo de nuevo màs tarde/ Error has been ocurred, try again later" i use this little variation of the code what you write

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/4.5.1/video-js.css" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/4.5.1/video.js"></script>
<script src="./src/youtube.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script>
function reload() {
$('#vidid source').attr('src', '<?=$id?>');
videojs("vidid", {}, function(){
    this.play();
});
} 
</script>
```

and in HTML

```
<video id="vidid" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay="autoplay" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"] }'>

<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/youtube" />
</video><a href="#" onclick="reload(); return false;" class="button">Mostrar envio</a>
```

That is similar to i have in other.php and it works fine... the youtube logo appears but when i press play, don t work, and send to me that message "Error has been ocurred, try again later"... like the URL/EMBED don t exist. But with the same text/url  "" it works in other.php. But not in the "ajax" one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function reload() {
    $('#vidid source').attr('src', 'other.php?&id=' + '<?=$id?>');
    videojs("vidid", {}, function(){
        this.load();
    });
}
```

Assuming the HTML is:

```
<video id="vidid" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>

<a href="#" onclick="reload(); return false;" class="button">Mostrar envio</a>
```

Changes based on comment below.

Comment: Unless Video.js has an attribute change event, I don't think this will solve it either as HTML5 has no such event (http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) from which to alert Video.js that source files have changed.

Comment: That helps. Updated response above.

Comment: i Can t answer my own topic because in newbie :S, i edit my first post for a little problem with the plugin code :S

Comment: One important change I recently made is in the reload() function. I changed "this.play()" to "this.load()". Does that help with the error?

Comment: I make that change and still occurs the error, with the MP4 the initial source can be "NOTHING" and the SRC in javascript can be a MP4 but when i change type='video/mp4' for type="video/youtube" and ADD data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"] }' ... The javascript function don t work ... Because i put a BAD url in the initial SRC and it DONT WORK, but i press "MOSTRAR ENVIO" , and dont change nothing. I put a CORRECT URL and it WORKS. and i press "Mostrar envio" and Dont change nothing... Maybe the plugin have another specific code?

Comment: I find this   // Copy the JavaScript options if they exists
    if (typeof options['source'] != 'undefined') {
      for (var key in options['source']) {
        player.options()[key] = options['source'][key];
      }
    }
 here https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/blob/master/src/youtube.js
That can be a "mirror syntax" of ur code for the plugin?

Comment: i use this code in javascript function myPlayer.src({ type: "video/youtube", src: "<?=$id?>" }); With it, the src change correctly and the youtube video works fine

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right, the problem is that Video.js isn't going to re-walk the DOM to find your video elements; loading video elements via AJAX (ie. your `reload()` function), or more importantly after Video.js has been initialized won't exist, to it.

I'm not familiar enough with Video.js, though, to tell you how best to resolve it.